# I have a menu with Textbutton but the buttons do not respond to the mouse

Tags: libgdx

public  class MainMenuGameScreen extends BaseScreen {

```
Texture charmander;
Texture button;
Skin skin;
Skin alternativa;
private ActorJugador charmandera;
private Actorcubo prota;
Animation animacione;
ArrayList<Sprite>animacion;
Music song;

@Override
public void initialize() {
    song = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music/Megalovania.mp3"));
    song.setLooping(true);
    song.setVolume(0.3f);
    song.play();
    animacion=new ArrayList<>();
    animacion=meterSprite(animacion);
    charmander=new Texture("charmader.png");
    button=new Texture("personaje0.png");

    BaseActor fondo=new BaseActor(0, 0, mainStage);
    fondo.setSize(800, 640);
    crearSkins();
    alternativa=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("craftacular/skin/craftacular-ui.json"));
    Label titulo = new Label("GEOMETRY DASH", alternativa);
    uiTable.add(titulo).center().width(250).height(120).pad(5);
    BaseActor background = new BaseActor(0, 0 , mainStage);
    TextButton button1 = new TextButton("nivel 1", skin);
    button1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Geometry.setActiveScreen(new Nivel1());
        pause();
        }
    });

    uiTable.row();
    uiTable.add(button1).center().width(250).height(100).pad(5);
    TextButton btn2 = new TextButton("nivel 2", skin);
    btn2.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //  CrazyJumper.setActiveScreen(new LevelScreen2());

            pause();
            }
        });

    uiTable.row();
    uiTable.add(btn2).center().width(250).height(100).pad(5);
    TextButton btn3 = new TextButton("nivel 3", skin);
    button1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        //  CrazyJumper.setActiveScreen(new LevelScreen1());
            System.out.println("nivel 3");
            pause();
        }
    });

    uiTable.row();
    uiTable.add(btn3).center().width(250).height(100).pad(5);

    TextButton btnsalir = new TextButton("salir", skin);
    btnsalir.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        //  CrazyJumper.setActiveScreen(new LevelScreen2());.
            pause();

        }
    });
    uiTable.row();
    uiTable.add(btnsalir).center().width(250).height(100).pad(5);
    uiTable.row();
    mainStage.addActor(uiTable);

}
private ArrayList<Sprite> meterSprite(ArrayList<Sprite> animacion2) {

    Sprite sprite1=new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("personaje0.png")));
    Sprite sprite2=new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("personaje1.png")));
    Sprite sprite3=new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("personaje2.png")));
    Sprite sprite4=new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("personaje3.png")));
animacion2.add(sprite1);
animacion2.add(sprite2);
animacion2.add(sprite3);
animacion2.add(sprite4);

    return animacion2;
}
private void crearSkins() {
    //creando fuente
    BitmapFont font=new BitmapFont();
    skin=new Skin();
    skin.add("default", font);
    //creando textura
    Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();
    skin.add("background", new Texture(pixmap));
    //estilo del boton
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle estilo=new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    estilo.up=skin.newDrawable("background",Color.GRAY);
    estilo.down=skin.newDrawable("background",Color.DARK_GRAY);
    estilo.checked=skin.newDrawable("background",Color.DARK_GRAY);
    estilo.over=skin.newDrawable("background",Color.BLUE);
    estilo.font=skin.getFont("default");
    skin.add("default", estilo);

}
public void show() {
    mainStage=new Stage();
    prota=new Actorcubo(button);
    charmandera=new ActorJugador(charmander);
    mainStage.addActor(prota);
    mainStage.addActor(charmandera);
    mainStage.addActor(uiTable);

    charmandera.setPosition(500, 200);
    prota.setPosition(100, 200);



}
public void pause() {
    song.pause();
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {


}
public void hide() {
    mainStage.dispose();
    charmander.dispose();
}

public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mainStage.act();
    comprobarColision();
    mainStage.draw();
}
private void comprobarColision() {
    if ((prota.getX() +prota.getWidth())>charmandera.getX()&&(prota.isAlive())) {
        System.out.println("colision");
        prota.setAlive(false);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should define the input processor for the screen:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageInstance);
```